# Compare java Date to SQLite Datetime

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I want to compare two dates, the today's date and the date when my data has been added to the database.
I can convert my `Date` to `String` and `String` to `Date`, but in my database the type of the "date" column is `DATETIME`. (I am using SQLite)
How could I compare the two dates?

My goal is to add only 1 row / day into the database

I atteched some example code:

```
if(currentDate.equals(dateAdded))
//some warning...
else
applyNewDataToDB();
```

Thank you, any answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, all native timestamps are date/time values - but using the formatting functions, you can filter out only time, or only dates, or both: see https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html combined with https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

With the following table layout :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (ID INTEGER primary key, theData VARCHAR(4), theDatetime REAL) ;
```

the query :

```
SELECT ID, theData 
FROM myTable 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', theDatetime,'unixepoch') >="2019-11-04" ;
```

is equivalent to :

```
SELECT ID, theData 
FROM myTable 
WHERE theDatetime >= 1572853740.0 ;
```